# CSS - Put an image centered on top of another

Tags: html, css, less

I have got to make a page with an image with width 100% which will be at the top of the page (I will call this one "img1").

Over img1, i have to put another image which i will call "img2", which will have a fixed size in px and will be centered.

img2 will be the background of a form, so then I'll put a form on it.

I have already read some posts on how to put an image on the top of another with relative and absolute nested divs, but then I can't use a margin auto; on img2, because it has an absolute position, and because it has a size in px, i can't even put a left in %, because it would move depending on the screen size.

I have tried another option which is using two nested divs with background-images with specified background-sizes (100% width for img1 and 500px width for img2), and centering img2 with background-position : it works, but then the div of img1 (which is empty of course, because I'm using a background-image), has no height.

When I was using an  tag, by putting 100% width on img1, the height was automatically defined because of the image ratio. But now with background-images I can't tell the div "hey, fit your height to the one your background-image please".

What do you suggest ? I hope I have well explained my problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe just put the first image as the background of the body tag set to top and no-repeat? The second image can be placed as the background of a div set to the correct width and height and with "margin: 0 auto" on it which should center it.

Comment: yes, I have already tried that : works the same, but the point is that if I use background-image I will have a div height of 0. There is no way I found yet apart from JavaScript to get the height of the div (which as width 100%) to fit the background image (wich has width 100% too and height depending on the image ratio).
That's why I would go for the <img> tag, but then I can't center the img2...
Maybe some CSS guru out there has the answer...

Comment: If you have the first image as a background on the BODY tag then you don't need to worry about the height of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand this :

> on img2, because it has an absolute position, and because it has a
>   size **in px**, i can't even put a left in %, because it would move
>   depending on the screen size.

You said img2 has a fixed size, it seems to me it's the perfect case for a centering with absolute position and negative margin.

Let's say your img2 is 200px wide :

```
.img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px /* negative half the width */
}
```

It would not work if img2 had a % size.

Comment: I am so dumb, I didn't think about the negative margin. Love you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS3 [multiple background images](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

This allows you to specify more than one background like so:

```
background-image: url(http://i153.photobucket.com/albums/s223/chibizim/110-baby-monkey.png), url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Standing-stone-state-forest-tn1.jpg);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XnNfU/1/)

Comment: I chose the other answer because it doesn't need CSS3 but this seems pretty functional, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try having your base image `absolute` and the picture that should go on top as `relative`, at the same time use `z-index` for the overlaying then if I have understood your question correctly it should work

Comment: this works for positioning, the problem i had was for centering the image then. bb